# Json Deserialize Exception converting String to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have very simple JSON string

`"{\"Region\":\"uk\"}"`

I am converting it to Dictionary like this

```
string  data =  "{\"Region\":\"uk\"}";
var dataOut = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);
```

The above code is working fine on  My Local and QA/UAT environments but giving following error on production server

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "{"Region":"uk"}" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'. Path '', line 1, position 21. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String].
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object value, Type initialType, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
```

Here is the [Dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jszWwv#) where the code is running fine

Newtonsoft.Json version is 7.0 but

The .Net framework version I have  on QA and UAT environments is **4.7.2558.0** but on production, it is **4.8.3761.0**

Is it be possible that .Net Framework 4.8 is the reason for this error.

Comment: I find it doubtful that the .Net Framework version is the culprit.  More likely you have different data.  If your JSON were to be double-serialized somehow, then you would see this exact error.  Here is a fork of your fiddle to demonstrate: https://dotnetfiddle.net/W9DOC1

Comment: But in the Elmah sever variables it is showing same json string which I posted with only one escape character

Comment: But you're only adding the escape characters to put the example JSON as a string literal  in your C# code, right?  The actual JSON should not have any escape characters in order to deserialize correctly.  It should be `{"Region":"uk"}`.  If you are seeing escape characters when you print out the JSON (not looking at it in a debugger) then that is the problem.

Comment: Yes you are right I will give it a try

Comment: Brian Rogers you were right, double-serialized was the issue, have fixed as you suggested, if you want to put it as an answer I'll mark it. Thanks